# Image Stored into database and want to retrive and display it on imageView

Tags: ios, sqlite

getting the image from imageview and stored that image to sqlite database 
the column datatype is BLOB it showing in database column image is like

```
<UIImage: 0x7fdb6e1f6790> size {199, 253} orientation 0 scale 1.000000
```

image string to image data and want to display it on image view .

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(init_statement, 6) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(init_statement, 6)];
    if(data == nil)
        NSLog(@"No image found.");
    else
        yourImageView = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Note: For More [Check this link](https://vitosolutions.wordpress.com/2012/05/25/save-image-data-to-sqlite-database-in-iphone/)